# White Box Testing - Basis Coverage

Tags: unit-testing, testing, white-box-testing

What does it mean, when you do a white box test :

**"cover the edges with a basis, if possible. Otherwise cover the paths with a set of arbitrary test cases"**.

What I usually do in this kind of exercises is to compute the cyclomatic complexity of my control graph , and then find a number of paths that is the same of my complexity. I wrote the test cases and I finished.

How do I verify if my edges coverage is a basis ?

Comment: What kind of coverage are you referring to?  Branch coverage or path coverage?  Moreover, I don't understand the term basis here - do you have a link to what is meant by that?

Comment: path coverage , a basis  is a set of paths that cover all the edges

Comment: That is probably a misunderstanding.  If your goal is to cover the edges, you are trying to achieve branch coverage.  To achieve branch coverage your test cases will typically only need to cover a subset of all possible paths.  In contrast, to achieve path coverage, you need one test case per path, that is, not only a subset of paths.